# NullpointerException Matcher

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, pattern-matching, matcher

I have some problem and i don't know how to  solve it! :)

```
Pattern tablep = Pattern.compile("(<table.*</table>)");
Matcher tablem = tablep.matcher(page);
if (tablem.find()) {table = tablem.group(1);}
```

here is `peace` of `regex` :([Docs](http://regexr.com?37of7))

Here's logcat:

```
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:177)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:90)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:297)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at com.example.portal_projekt_2.Schedule.getHtm(Schedule.java:103)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at com.example.portal_projekt_2.Schedule.createFolder(Schedule.java:93)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at com.example.portal_projekt_2.Schedule.onCreate(Schedule.java:37)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-22 17:17:49.237: E/AndroidRuntime(6851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
```

I am sure that page contains String

Comment: Use a HTML parser such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: what is line 103 `Schedule.java`?. Use jsoup for parsing html.

Comment: I dont think it will works.. Because i m getting html content (page) from httpclient... Before i m logging by httpclient so i have cookies(I cant get "mypage" without cookies)...  Sorry for my bad English (Hope you understand :) )

Comment: schedule 103     Matcher tablem = tablep.matcher(page);

Comment: I solved it :)  I m not shure but maybe problewm was:                               String table = null;                                                   Pattern tablep = Pattern.compile("(<table.*</table>)");
Matcher tablem = tablep.matcher(page);
if (tablem.find()) {table = tablem.group(1);}